# Python sys.exc_info in finally prints an exception that can't be caught

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code:

```
import contextlib
import sys

class CC:
    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        return True

@contextlib.contextmanager
def ctx():
    try:
        with CC():
            yield
    except:
        print("has exception")
        raise
    finally:
        print("finally")
        print(sys.exc_info())

def test():
    with ctx():
        raise ValueError()

test()
```

It's a bit convoluted. But the idea is that I'm raising an exception inside the context `ctx`. Because `CC` returns `True` on exit, the exception should be [suppressed](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__) . So I expect that the `except` clause would not execute, and that the `sys.exc_info()` in the `finally` clause prints nothing.

But the reality is, the `except` clause does not execute, but `sys.exc_info()` in the `finally` clause prints the original exception. This confuses me because isn't `__exit__` returning True supposed to suppress the exception? And why is there a discrepancy between the exception that `except` and `sys.exc_info()` see?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question.

So in a context manager (either with `@contextmanager` or explicitly defined `__exit__`), when there's an exception it gets thrown out of the `yield`. Essentially the rest of the code is being executed in the `except` of the throwing code. The context manager can of course catch and suppress the re-raised exception, but it doesn't change the fact that it's in the `except` clause, so it's still dealing with the original exception. That means even if the re-raised exception is caught and suppressed, `sys.exc_info()` will still show the original one.

With an example, this means

```
@contextmanager
def ctx():
    try:
        try:
            yield
        except:
            pass
    except:
        assert False
    finally:
        print(sys.exc_info())

with ctx():
    raise ValueError()
```

will print the original `ValueError` in `finally`, although the outer `except` will not catch anything.

Furthermore, I think this means that context managers aren't completely drop-in replacements for code refactoring.

```
with ctx:
    try:
        foo()
    except:
        ...
```

can't always be transformed into

```
@contextmanager
def fun():
    with ctx:
        try:
            yield
        except:
            ...

with fun():
    do_something()
```